# UseEffect Running infinitely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I have to make an api call that gets me a list.
So i am dispatching an action inside useEffect that makes an api call and then dispatches an action that is consumed by the reducer, which in turn returns updated state..
But the problem is when the component gets mounted useEffect is called infinitely..
I have tried-
1- Adding the dependencies inside the UseEffect
2- Passing empty array of dependencies..

This is the component in Question-

```js
import * as React from 'react';
import { TableBody, TableRow, TableCell, Toolbar, Grid, Typography, Box, MenuItem, FormControl } from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';
import useTable from 'components/common/useTable';
import Controls from 'components/common/controls/Controls';
import { InputAdornment } from '@material-ui/core';
import { CloudDownload, Search } from '@material-ui/icons';
import TableDropdown from 'components/common/tableDropdown/TableDropdown';
import useNavTabs from 'components/common/useNavTabs';
import BasicModal from 'components/common/usePopper'
import { Button } from '@mui/material';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { getDSAList, dsaCommentAndStatusUpdate } from 'containers/DSA/actions';
import {MultiSelect} from 'components/common/controls/MultiSelect'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/styles';
import { DetailsModel } from 'components/common/detailsModel';
import { IconButton } from '@mui/material';
import { Autocomplete } from '@mui/material';
import { TextField } from '@mui/material';
import theme from 'assets/theme';
import {useEffect} from 'react'

const useStyles = makeStyles({
  clearFilterBtn: {
    color: '#f58720',
    padding: '0.7rem 2.2rem',
    display: 'block',
    margin: '0.4rem auto',
    "&:hover": {
      color: '#f58720',
    },
    "&:active": {
      color: '#f58720',
    },
    "&:focus:not(:hover)": {
      color: '#f58720',
    },
  },
    'MuiTableCell-root': {
        color: "#000"
    },
    "MuiIconButton-Root": {
      color: theme.palette.light.orange,
      "&:hover": {
        color: theme.palette.light.yellow
      },
      "&:active": {
        color: theme.palette.light.yellow,
      },
      "&:focus:not(:hover)": {
        color: theme.palette.light.orange
      }
    },
    "MuiInputBase-root": {
        height: '7vh'
    },
    ".MuiFormControl-root": {
      marginTop: '1rem'
    }
})


const headCells = [
  {id:'sno', label:'S.No.'}, 
  {id:'dsaId', label: 'DSA ID' },
  {id:'dsaName', label: 'DSA Name'}, 
  {id:'primarySourcingBusiness', label: 'Primary Sourcing Business'}, 
  {id:'dsaType', label: 'DSA Type'}, 
  {id:'bdmName', label:'BDM Name'}, 
  {id:'date', label:'Date'}, 
  {id:'registrationStatus', label: 'Registration Status'}
]
const headCellsMapping = [
  {id:'sno', label:'S.No.'}, 
  {id:'dsaId', label: 'DSA ID' },
  {id:'dsaName', label: 'DSA Name'}, 
  {id:'dsaContact', label: 'DSA Contact'}, 
  {id:'dsaType', label: 'DSA Type'}, 
  {id:'bdmName', label:'BDM Name'}, 
]

export default function DSARegistrationVerification() {

  const [filterFn, setFilterFn] = useState({ fn: items => { return items; } })
  const [enteredSearch, setEnteredSearch] = React.useState('')
  const [cityNames, setCityNames] = React.useState([])
  const[PSBNames,setPSBNames] = React.useState([])
  const[DSAType, setDSAType] = React.useState([])
  const[regStatus, setRegStatus] = React.useState([])
  const[selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = React.useState()
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(enteredSearch)
    const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('sending request')
          dispatch(getDSAList({
            page: 1,
            pageSize: 10,
            searchString: enteredSearch
          }))
        }, 500);
        return () => {
          console.log('cleanup')
          clearTimeout(identifier)
        }
    }, [enteredSearch]) 
    const dsaRecord = useSelector((state) => state.dsa)
  
    const handleChange = (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    };
  
    const handleSubmission = () => {
      console.log(DSAType, regStatus, PSBNames, cityName)
      dispatch(getDSAList({
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 10,
        filters: `${cityName.length > 0 ? 'cityName:'+cityName[0]:''}${PSBNames.length > 0 ? ',primarySourcingBusiness:'+PSBNames[0]: ''}${dsaType.length > 0 ? ',dsaType:' + dsaType[0]: ''}${regStatus.length > 0 ? ',registrationStatus'+regStatus[0]: ''}`
      }))
    }
  const classes = useStyles()
  const {
    TblContainer, 
    TblHead, 
    TblPagination,
    TblSort,
  } = useTable(dsaRecord.dsaList || [], headCells,filterFn)

  const {NavTabsHead,NavTabPanel} = useNavTabs()

  const fetchData= () =>{
    dispatch(getDSAList({
      page: 1,
      pageSize: 10,
      searchString: enteredSearch
    }))
  }

  // const handleSubmission = () => {
  //   console.log(DSAType, regStatus, PSBNames, cityName)
  //   dispatch(getDSAList({
  //     page: 1,
  //     pageSize: 10,
  //     filters: `${cityName.length > 0 ? 'cityName:'+cityName[0]:''}${PSBNames.length > 0 ? ',primarySourcingBusiness:'+PSBNames[0]: ''}${dsaType.length > 0 ? ',dsaType:' + dsaType[0]: ''}${regStatus.length > 0 ? ',registrationStatus'+regStatus[0]: ''}`
  //   }))
  // }

  // const handleChange = (e, v) => {
  //     console.log('......................>',v)
  //     setSelectedValue(v)
  // }

  const handleDSAMapping = () => {
    dispatch(dsaCommentAndStatusUpdate(
      {
        dsaUserId: 'DSA1',
        bdmUserId: 'BDM1',
        registrationStatus:'Approved',
        comment:"any thing"
    }
    ))
  }

  const cityName = ['Mumbai', 'Banglore', 'Pune']
  const primarySourcingBusiness = ['Gold Loan', 'Car Loan', 'Home Loan', 'abc', 'xyz', '123', 'antidisestablishmentarianism']
  const dsaType=['Individual', 'Test', 'Test 2']
  const registrationStatus=['Pending', 'Approved','Rejected']
  const dsaNames= ['Enrique Jefferson','Keyan Ingram','Gemma Holland','Radhika Keenan','Aryaan Sheehan','Lacy Rivas']
  const selectRef = React.useRef()

  const handleSearch = (value) => {
    setEnteredSearch(value)
  }
  const handleChangePage = (page) => {
    dispatch(getDSAList({
      page: page,
      pageSize: "10",
      searchString: enteredSearch
    }))
  }

  const selected = event => {
    console.log(event.target.innerText)
    setSelectedValue(event.target.innerText)
  }
  return (
    <>
      <Toolbar disableGutters>
              <Grid container>
                  <Grid item md={4}>
                    <Controls.InputEl
                        label="Search DSA"
                        sx={{width: '80%'}}
                        InputProps={{
                            endAdornment: (
                                <InputAdornment position='start'>
                                    <Search/>
                                </InputAdornment>
                            )
                        }}
                        handleSearch={handleSearch}
                    />
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item md={4} sx={{paddingTop: 3}}>
                    <TblSort/> <span>&nbsp;</span>
                    <BasicModal 
                      triggerName={"Filter"}
                      triggerIcon={"filterList"}
                      heading={'Filter'}
                      footerButtonName={'Apply'}
                      placement={'bottom-start'}
                      onFormAction={handleSubmission}>
                      <Grid item md={12} sx={{padding: '0.3rem 0.5rem'}}>
                        <MultiSelect
                          label="City Name"
                          options={cityName}
                          handleChange={(values) => setCityNames(values)}
                          selectProps={{
                            msgNoOptionsAvailable: 'All cities are selected',
                            msgNoOptionsMatchFilter: 'No city name matches the filter',
                          }}
                        />
                      </Grid>  
                      <Grid item md={12} sx={{padding: '0.3rem 0.5rem'}}>
                        <MultiSelect
                          label="Primary Sourcing Business"
                          options={primarySourcingBusiness}
                          handleChange={(value) => setPSBNames(value)}
                          selectProps={{
                            msgNoOptionsAvailable: 'All cities are selected',
                            msgNoOptionsMatchFilter: 'No city name matches the filter',
                          }}
                        />
                      </Grid>  
                      <Grid item md={12} sx={{padding: '0.3rem 0.5rem'}}>
                        <MultiSelect
                          label="DSA Type"
                          options={dsaType}
                          handleChange={(value) => setDSAType(value)}
                          selectProps={{
                            msgNoOptionsAvailable: 'All cities are selected',
                            msgNoOptionsMatchFilter: 'No city name matches the filter',
                          }}
                        />
                      </Grid>  
                      <Grid item md={12} sx={{padding: '0.3rem 0.5rem'}}>
                        <MultiSelect
                          label="Registration Status"
                          options={registrationStatus}
                          handleChange={(value) => setRegStatus(value)}
                          selectProps={{
                            msgNoOptionsAvailable: 'All Status Selected',
                            msgNoOptionsMatchFilter: 'No Status Type Matched The filter',
                          }}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                      <Grid item md={12}>
                          <Button fullWidth className={classes.clearFilterBtn}>
                              Clear All filters
                          </Button>
                      </Grid> 
                    </BasicModal>
                  </Grid>
                  <Grid item md={4} sx={{paddingTop: 3, display:'flex', justifyContent: 'end'}} >
                  <IconButton
                    id="download-button"
                    className={classes['MuiIconButton-Root']}
                  >
                    <CloudDownload/>
                  <Typography sx={{color: theme.palette.light.orange, fontSize: '0.8rem'}} variant='h6' ml={1}>
                    Download Excel
                  </Typography>
                </IconButton>
                  </Grid>
                </Grid>  
            </Toolbar>  
            <Grid item md={12}>
              <TblContainer>
                  <TblHead/>
                  <TableBody>
                    {dsaRecord && dsaRecord.dsaList?
                      dsaRecord.dsaList.map(
                        (record, index) =>
                        <TableRow key={index}>
                          <TableCell className={classes['MuiTableCell-root']}>{index}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>
                            <Typography sx={{color: theme.palette.light.orange, fontSize: '0.9rem'}}>
                              <DetailsModel triggerName={record.dsaUserId} tabCount={3}/>
                            </Typography>
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell className={classes['MuiTableCell-root']}>
                              {record.dsaName}
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell className={classes['MuiTableCell-root']}>{record.primarySourcingBusiness}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell className={classes['MuiTableCell-root']}>{record.dsaType}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell className={classes['MuiTableCell-root']}>
                            <Box component="div" sx={{display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'space-between'}}>
                                <Typography variant={'body2'}>
                                  {record.bdmUserName}
                                </Typography>
                                <BasicModal
                                triggerName={""}
                                triggerIcon={"edit"}
                                dsaUserId={record.dsaUserId}
                                heading={'BDM Name'}
                                footerButtonName={'Done'}
                                onFormAction={handleDSAMapping}
                                >
                                  <Grid item md={12} sx={{padding: '0.3rem 0.5rem'}}>
                                  <Autocomplete
                                    disablePortal
                                    id="combo-box-demo"
                                    options={dsaNames}
                                    sx={{ width: 300 }}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="BDM" />}
                                  />
                                  </Grid>
                                </BasicModal>
                            </Box>
                          </TableCell>
                          <TableCell className={classes['MuiTableCell-root']}>{record.registrationDate}</TableCell>
                          <TableCell>
                              <TableDropdown status ={record.registrationStatus} />
                          </TableCell>
                      </TableRow>
                      ): ''}
                  </TableBody>
              </TblContainer>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item md={12}>
              <TblPagination pageSize={dsaRecord && dsaRecord.pageSize} totalPages={dsaRecord && dsaRecord.totalPages} pageNumber={dsaRecord.currentPage || 1}
              handleChangePage={(page) => handleChangePage(page-1)}/>
            </Grid>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is my useEffect

```js
useEffect(() => {
  console.log(enteredSearch)
  const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('sending request')
    dispatch(getDSAList({
      page: 1,
      pageSize: 10,
      searchString: enteredSearch
    }))
  }, 500);
  return () => {
    console.log('cleanup')
    clearTimeout(identifier)
  }
}, [enteredSearch])
```

This is the Action

```js
export const getDSAList = (searchData) => {
    return async (dispatch) => {
        const fetchData = async () => {
            console.log('Fetching Data')
            const response = await webApiCall.post('https://a30fa91e-ae8b-42fb-8439-c2cc2d3cedfe.mock.pstmn.io/dsa/api/user/list',searchData)
            if(response.data.status !== 200) {
                throw new Error('Could not fetch DSA List')
            }
            return response.data.dsaResponse
        }

        try {
            const dsaData = await fetchData()
            dispatch(dsaActions.fetchDSAList(dsaData))
        }
        catch(error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This is the Reducer

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const dsaSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'dsa',
    initialState: {},
    reducers: {
        fetchDSAList(state, action) {
            state.dsaList = action.payload.dsaList 
        },
        commentAndStatusUpdate(state, action) {
            state.commentAndStatusUpdate = action.payload
        }
    }
})
export const dsaActions = dsaSlice.actions
export default dsaSlice;
```

This is the store

```js
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { loginSlice } from 'containers/signin/reducer'
import { logoutSlice } from 'containers/signout/reducer'
import dsaSlice from 'containers/DSA/reducer'
// Export store with reducers
export const store = configureStore({
    preloadedState:{},
    reducer: {
        signin: loginSlice.reducer,
        signout: logoutSlice.reducer,
        dsa: dsaSlice.reducer
    }
})

export const loginActions = loginSlice.actions
export const logoutActions = logoutSlice.actions
```

Comment: Where is the useEffect located? In which .js?

Comment: It's located inside the component that requires the state....
I am updating the question with the component as well

Comment: What is `enteredSearch`? If it's coming from a `useState()` in the same component, it shouldn't run infinitely.

Comment: enteredSearch is coming from useState, 
it is used for storing user input ..

Comment: i'm sorry, im a bit lost in your code.
I seen "enteredsearch" is a state.
The value is inserted 
`  const handleSearch = (value) => {
    setEnteredSearch(value)
  }`
What is this "Controls.InputEl"?

Comment: Ok so this is a bit more complex than you probably think it is. You probably want to debounce the change handler with a `useCallback` (instead of `useEffect`). This triggers the request only if the user stopped typing for a bit. In addition to that, you need to take into account that search results from certain requests might arrive later than expected and overwrite stuff in your reducer. I'd offload all of that to thunks to make it easier. The component should only have to debounce the change handler.

Comment: Controls.inputEl is a reusable component that renders a Material ui TextField Element in the dom.

Comment: I simplified the useEffect by removing the code for debouncing,
so now the useEffect only has dispatch() inside it and entered search as dependency, but still same problem

Comment: Have you tried adding a simple `console.log(enteredSearch);` to see why the effect gets triggered? It should reflect the input string. Maybe you're getting something else you're not expecting.

Comment: @timotgl, yes.. i have tried that... the value isn't changing..

Comment: Hm very strange. There's something else at play here or one of your assumptions is wrong. Is the component get re-mounted for some reason maybe? Have you verified that it is in fact only the effect that runs again and again even if `enteredSearch` does not change?

Comment: @timotgl Thank you for taking your time... It was a silly mistake
In the store, i was passing reducers without using combineReducer, so after that.. it worked fine..

Comment: @KaushikGarkoti please share [MWE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Chandan do you want the working code..?

Comment: @KaushikGarkoti minimal working example on where the issue is reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

try to remove enteredSearch and put the code like this i think it will work , it worked on my side

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(enteredSearch)
    const identifier = setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('sending request')
          dispatch(getDSAList({
            page: 1,
            pageSize: 10,
            searchString: enteredSearch
          }))
        }, 500);
        return () => {
          console.log('cleanup')
          clearTimeout(identifier)
        }
    }, [])
```

Comment: This will only run once when mounting the component.

Comment: i have tried that already, but it didn't work